# Create zip with no extension

Tags: r, zip

I want to create a zip file called "out" not "out.zip". When I run this line:

```
zip("out", zippedfiles)
```

where `zippedfiles` is a list of files, I get `out.zip`. I am doing this in a Windows environment.

Thanks.

Comment: This is likely a Windows problem not an R problem.  We'll see if anyone thinks differently though.

Comment: @gsk3  It's zip, not Windows.  :)

Comment: @Iterator Note to self: Insert foot in mouth.  Kick violently.

Comment: I'm actually wondering why you'd want to create a file without an extension. IME this tends to create more problems, because you lose the information about the file type that you might need later on.

Comment: offtopic response to Hong Ooi:  the file extension has nothing to do with file information (aka "metadata").  You can change any file's extension and nothing happens except that the OS associates the file with the 'wrong' application.  rename foo.doc to foo.zip, then open Word and select Open/foo.zip and it's still a Word file.

Comment: Yes, Carl is right. This file is being returned as a 64 bit encoded stream from a web service. For the sake of simplicity, we wrote all of the services and R scripts to expect inputs called "in" and outputs called "out". Then the client worries about what the file type is and what to do with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several people have mentioned that this is the behaviour of zip, but not why this is the cause of what you are seeing. If you look at the source for `zip()` or even the help `?zip`, it should be immediately clear that the behaviour you are seeing comes from the system `zip` function and nothing to do with R itself. All R does is call the system function for zipping, which by default is `zip`:

```
R> zip
function (zipfile, files, flags = "-r9X", extras = "", zip = Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", 
    "zip")) 
{
    if (missing(flags) && (!is.character(files) || !length(files))) 
        stop("'files' must a character vector specifying one or more filepaths")
    args <- c(flags, shQuote(path.expand(zipfile)), shQuote(files), 
        extras)
    invisible(system2(zip, args, invisible = TRUE)) ## simply calling system command
}
<bytecode: 0x27faf30>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

If you are annoyed by the extension, just issue a `file.rename()` call after the call to `zip()`:

```
file.rename("out.zip", "out")
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I suggested.

Comment: @Gavin and others: Renaming is most sensible.  Although naming the target initially is simpler, the `file.rename()` approach is safer.  By wrapping it in `if(!file.exists(target))`, one can avoid overwriting the target.  In fact, using a temporary file, such as `tempfile()` is even safer.  Safety first!  :)  It stinks to create an output file that requires a lot of computation and then accidentally overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, no extension is used if I append `.` (i.e. a period) to the filename, e.g. `out.` should work.  The full expression: `zip("out.", zippedfiles)`.

For what it's worth, this is due to the default behavior of zip, and is not an issue with R or Windows.

---

Update 1: In general, it is better to avoid an approach that is OS-specific.  I think this approach may create issues if the code is run on other platforms.  Gavin's answer, involving renaming, is more portable.  What's more, as I suggested in the comments, testing if the target exists using `file.exists()`, before renaming, adds another layer of safety.  An additional layer of safety is obtained by getting a temporary filename via `tempfile()`.  An alternative method of avoiding name collisions when writing or renaming is to use a timestamp in the name.